# Bypass UEFI on native Windows 8 Acer Aspire V5

Tags: windows-8, boot, uefi, acer-aspire

I'm working on an ACER Aspire V5-121 OEM Windows 8.
The original hard drive with the OS was removed, and I have a blank one... but could not install any other OS on it, not even Win 8.

As the V5-121 is a netbook, it doesn't have a disk drive in it, so the only way is to boot from USB... I tryied in so many different ways and I have 2 different messages:
1 - No bootable device - Press any key >>> Boot menu, select device... but doesn't show any device.
2 - Show Acer wallpaper, and nothing more.

I tryed to install Debian (last version) and also Win 8, but nothing.
I read somewhere that could be a UEFI problem. It blocks booting from other devices, but I don't know how to bypass/disable it without OS inside my hard drive...

Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You cannot "disable" UEFI that is your firmware, it is basically the BIOS, and you can't disable or bypass BIOS.

Comment: Yeah, basically I know that. But how can I access it to access it without OS? I know how to access it and work on it from windows 8, the problem is that I don't have any OS on my hard drive at the moment... and I would like to install one. 
Sorry if I was not clear before, and thanks again for any suggestion.

Comment: Clarify your question.  How you access the firmware options depends on the manufacture.  Since you have an Acer they key would be [F2 then when prompted F12](http://acer.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3182/~/why-cant-i-get-the-f12-boot-menu-to-work-on-my-notebook-or-netbook%3F)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your BIOS menu, and look for anything that has UEFI in it, and change to "legacy", if your BIOS supports that, most BIOSs should support that.
Also did you make sure the USB you are using is bootable??
run (on another system) "sudo fdisk /dev/sdX" where sdX is your drive's node, then issue p, and see if you have the bootable flag next to any of the partitions.
If you are using UEFI/GPT, fdisk won't work for you, but parted/gparted will.

Comment: I used Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool as suggested in some official guides, the problem is (I think) I cannot access the bios/uefi to let the system boot from usb...

Comment: try installing win8.1

Comment: Tryed right now... same situation. "No bootable device, Hit any key" 
Then black screen